# local environment stopped loading <body>

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp

I've been running my local environment via MAMP. And randomly today it stopped loading my page!

I checked the page source and everything under the `<head>` is loaded but nothing under `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, are you doing some modul loading inside your html? If these files are located in a different (sub)directory, there might be a permission problem. 
Set your folder to read only for all and apply it to all inculded files and folders.

Greetings,
Peter